# Cron like scheduling using Apache Oozie

Tags: mapreduce, scheduling, jobs, oozie

http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/04/how-to-use-cron-like-scheduling-in-apache-oozie/

I referred this link which shows us how to schedule jobs using cron like syntax. But it shows scheduling in CDH4 and CDH5. Can anyone tell me how this can be achieved in CDH3? We have a CDH3 cluster.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the 'cron-like' scheduling functionality wasn't included until Oozie 4.1.0.  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OOZIE-1306.  CDH3 is only running a 2.X.X release I believe.

However, you may be in some luck if you're willing to compile Oozie by hand an install / update your current version.  Here are the only requirements for Oozie 4.1.0 :

```
Unix box (tested on Mac OS X and Linux)
Java JDK 1.6+
Maven 3.0.1+
Hadoop 0.20.2+
Pig 0.7+
```

All of which are covered in CDH3.  https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.1.0/DG_QuickStart.html